# Editing before vote to close

Tags: discussion, editing, question-quality, vote-to-close

In this [question on meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3159/33055) I requested that the [Edit] button on the Close Vote review queue items would not imply that I want to leave the question open.

The cause of this, is that questions are currently initiated to be voted to be closed without the "initiator" taking any effort to make the question more readable (spelling, grammar, formatting and removal of cruft (thanks, names, appreciation, pretty please, I am new to Linux, etc.)).

As there are normally at least four more people that have to read through the Q and agree with you to close the Q, it would
be appropriate to make their lives somewhat easier by getting the question in a more presentable shape. I think it also gives a better message to the OP, as it is clear we put some effort in trying to get the Q in shape, but it is not enough.

Should we encourage the close vote "initiators" to edit (if appropriate/possible), and if so how can I/we do so?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't fix what your suggesting, which I 100% agree with, by the way. But I'll typically open the Q outside of the review queue, in another tab, make the edits, and then click the "Leave Closed" option after making the edits.

#### Bit of a diatribe

My general approach/philosophy to being a good community member, is that we should edit Q's and make then as correct and presentable as possible. I've done so on Q's that we've then migrated or even closed there after. All in the hopes of leaving them in as good a state as I/we possibly can, hoping that the OP will be able to pick them up from there, add/fix what needs to be done so by them, so that we can then reopen them and get them answered.

Comment: I agree and I do that as well if I get an improvable Q in the queue (as described in my feature request, did not copy that part to the current question). But that doesn't solve reducing the number of improvable Qs getting into the queue (i.e. educating the initiators of closing a Q).

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to polish a turd, but even with mediocre questions it's often best to edit them to some extent. Even if the question should be closed, often an edit makes it more clear that the question should be closed. Give it decent (if not perfect) tags so that it's seen by the right people, give it a title that reflects what the question is really about, ensure that it has one or two comprehensible sentences that make it clear that the question is off-topic, too broad, etc.

If you have no idea what the question is about, and you don't think it's a matter of not being familiar with the topic, vote to close as unclear and move on.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer my question on *how* I can encourage a "close vote initiator", but when appropriate I can sent them a link to this answer in a chat message.

Comment: @Anthon I answered the “should we” part. As to how encourage, well, I don't think there's any particular need to actively encourage others on a question-to-question basis. If you feel the question needs editing, edit it.

Comment: You're right you did. I should read my own questions more carefully. Excuse is that I already had an opinion on the first part, but no ideas for the second part.